# Bind User Control To Parent Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

How Can I Bind User Control To Parent Window At The Bottom Of The Window?

Comment: I think that you meant dock instead of bind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dock it to the bottom of the window, you should use a DockPanel around it:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Label
        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
        Content="I will be docked to the bottom of the window."/>
</DockPanel>
```